# YII CJuiDatePicker in a index _view

Tags: yii

I want to add a datepicker to my _view, so each item has the option to select a date. I'm going to save the date with AJAX afterwards, but I can't get the datepicker to work.

So in my index I call, as standard the _view to display the items:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>'{items} {pager}',
        'id'=>"post_list",
    )); ?>
```

So now I have to wrap the datepicker in a form and bind to a model or something, but I don't know how to do that... So what I've got now in my _view is:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'agenda-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'gebDatum',
            'language'=>'nl',
            'options' => array(
                'showAnim' => 'fold',
                'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                'yearRange'=>'-70:+0',
                'changeYear'=>true,
                'changeMonth'=>true,
            ),
        ));
    ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Which is obviously not going to work, but can someone help me here to do this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, fixed it.. I imported a _form, containing the datepicker, into my _view with:`$model=new Vacature;$this->renderPartial('//vacature/_form', array('model'=>$model));`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it. I imported a _form, containing the datepicker, into my _view with

```
$model=new Vacature;
$this->renderPartial('//vacature/_form', array('model'=>$model));
```